# Event emitting and listening on directive scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I have this snippet of code here, which is part of a directive.

```js
return {
      restrict: "E",
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: "ui/components/captionSection.html",
      scope: {
        captions: "<?",
        vidDuration: "<?",
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        
        
        $rootScope.$on("youtube.player.playing", function ($event, player) {
          
        });

        scope.$on("youtube.player.playing", function ($event, player) {
         
        });
       

        scope.$on("$destroy", function ($event) {
          console.log($event);
          $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
          element.remove();
        });
      },
    };
```

The event it's listening to are triggered by [this](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed) package, more specifically this function.

```js
function applyBroadcast () {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$emit.apply(scope, args);
                });
            }
```

My question is why am I able to catch the event with only the $rootScope and not with the directive scope. I can catch the event on a controller with $scope, isn't the behaviour the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on where in the tree the source and listener are

Comment: What do you mean by tree?

Comment: DOM tree.... ... An emit in one branch only goes up that branch

Comment: Can you provide some more information, or point me to where I can find that information?
Also how can I tell where from the event is being emitted? Since it's an exterior package, I'm only including it in index.html and as a dependency to the app module. Then using it as a directive element.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit